# Near by search on google maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

We want to implement a logistic software program to fetch all the places between two locations.
As an example A is the starting point and B is the destination. Now we would like to fetch all the area names with in a radius of 500 Meters from the google maps at starting point (A), destination point (B) and all the places between A and B.

Is there any API which can be integrated or any kind of help is welcome!!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get stopover towns using the Google Maps API (directions)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14641899/get-stopover-towns-using-the-google-maps-api-directions)

Answer (score -1):

Of course there is! You should use [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search#PlaceSearchRequests) and feed it with the points (lat, alt) that you get from your Google Maps route. Remember to use the radar function.

Comment: Any example? That is not a valuable answer if you don't explain how you'd do it.

Comment: Hi Mr.Salvador. Thank you for the reply. We want to pass location name insted of Lat, alt. Can you please give us a small example on radar function usage..??