# how to get city name using latitude and longitude in android

Tags: android, google-maps, indexoutofboundsexception, reverse-geocoding

I am trying to get city in TextView using latitude and longitude. I am getting `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

**AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import static com.example.khaledsb.location.R.id.lng;
import static java.util.Locale.*;

public class AndroidGPSTrackingActivity extends Activity {

    public static float distFrom(float lat1, float lng1, float lat2, float lng2) {
        double earthRadius = 6371000; //meters
        double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2-lat1);
        double dLng = Math.toRadians(lng2-lng1);
        double a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
                Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) *
                        Math.sin(dLng/2) * Math.sin(dLng/2);
        double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
        float dist = (float) (earthRadius * c);

        return dist;
    }

    Button btnShowLocation;

    // GPSTracker class
    GPSTracker gps;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        btnShowLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShowLocation);

          final TextView lat =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.lat);
          final TextView lon = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.longt);
          final TextView addr = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.address);

        // show location button click event
        btnShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {        
                // create class object
                gps = new GPSTracker(AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.this);

                // check if GPS enabled     
                if(gps.canGetLocation()){

                    double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                    double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

                    double Distance;
                    Distance = distFrom((float) 36.5925907, 2.9051544f, 36.5805505f, 2.914749f);

                    lat.setText(String.valueOf(latitude));
                    lon.setText(String.valueOf(longitude));


                    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.this, Locale.ENGLISH);

                    try {
                        List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);

                        if(addresses != null) {
                            Address returnedAddress = addresses.get(0);
                            StringBuilder strReturnedAddress = new StringBuilder("Address:\n");
                            for(int i=0; i<returnedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                                strReturnedAddress.append(returnedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
                            }
                            addr.setText(strReturnedAddress.toString());
                        }
                        else{
                            addr.setText("No Address returned!");
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        addr.setText("Can not get Address!");
                    }

                    // \n is for new line
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude+" " +
                            //"  diastance "+Distance, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else{
                    // can't get location
                    // GPS or Network is not enabled
                    // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
                    gps.showSettingsAlert();
                }

            }
        });
    }

}
```

I am getting the following error in logcat :

```
5-09 11:17:21.858 4501-4501/com.example.khaledsb.location E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
     java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
                                                                                 at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
     at com.example.khaledsb.location.AndroidGPSTrackingActivity$1.onClick(AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.java:79)
     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Check below link you can get whole address online: [Get complete address from lat and long](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9409195/how-to-get-complete-address-from-latitude-and-longitude)

Comment: There are many solutions available for your question. You can dig a google.

Comment: why down voting, you should comment.

Comment: @AseshaGeorge To whom you'r saying ??

Comment: those who downvoted

Comment: They are downvoted because they might be thought question as duplicate or primary option based. @AseshaGeorge

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
List<Address> addresses = null;
try {
    addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
    String locality = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
}
```

Comment: asking to use try catch

Comment: Please share lat, lng values

Comment: i got it i just changed 1,1 to latitude and longitude

Comment: i don't know why somebody give down voting to my question

Answer (score 5):

Use below code to get city name

```
 Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);

    try {
        List<Address>addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude,longitue,1);
        if (geocoder.isPresent()) {
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            if (addresses.size()>0) {
                Address returnAddress = addresses.get(0);

                String localityString = returnAddress.getLocality();
                String name = returnAddress.getFeatureName();
                String subLocality = returnAddress.getSubLocality();
                String country = returnAddress.getCountryName();
                String region_code = returnAddress.getCountryCode();
                String zipcode = returnAddress.getPostalCode();
                String state = returnAddress.getAdminArea();

            }
        } else {

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, Hope it helps..

```
private static String getRegionName(double lati, double longi) {
    String regioName = "";
    Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(AppInstance, Locale.getDefault());
    try {
        List<Address> addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(lati, longi, 1);
        if (addresses.size() > 0) {
            regioName = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return regioName;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use following code to get complete address,

```
//Get address from Google api
        //Log.e("Else","else");
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObj = getJSONfromURL("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + latitude + ","
                    + longitude + "&sensor=true");
            String Status = jsonObj.getString("status");
            if (Status.equalsIgnoreCase("OK")) {
                JSONArray Results = jsonObj.getJSONArray("results");
                JSONObject location = Results.getJSONObject(0);
                finalAddress = location.getString("formatted_address");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

instead of,

```
geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

For Avoid ArrayIndexOutOfBound you could add if condition like below:

```
if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
    String locality = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
}
```

but, as I saw your code you are trying to get address using GeoCoder inside button click, So avoid this because it is a network call. You should not perform network call in main thread, it could block UI Or Cause ANR. You should use AsyncTask/Thread for network operation to avoid blocking Of UI.

Also make sure you have added

> INTERNET_PERMISSION

in your manifest file.

Hope It help you !

Answer (score 0):

Error states that the Array list is empty so make sure you initialize the list and check if it contains any data.

try this code:

```
List<Address> addresses = new List<Address>;

addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(addresses != null) {
String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
String state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
String postalCode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
String knownName = addresses.get(0).getFeatureName();
```

}

This should give you required info.

Answer (score 0):

Fetching location address from latlong co-ordinates fetched from Location object.

```
@Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        
        String longitude = "Longitude: " + location.getLongitude();
        Log.v(TAG, longitude);

        String latitude = "Latitude: " + location.getLatitude();
        Log.v(TAG, latitude);
        
        String address = null;
        String knownName = null;
        String city = null;
        String state = null;
        String country = null;
        String postalCode = null;

        Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(MainActivity.this.getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
        List<Address> addresses;

        try {
            addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);

            address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
            if (addresses.get(0).getFeatureName() != address) {
                knownName = addresses.get(0).getFeatureName();
            }
            city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
            state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
            country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
            postalCode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String foundAddress = knownName + ", " + address + ", " + city + ", " + state + ", " + country + "- " + postalCode + "\n";

        myLocation.setText(foundAddress);
        storeLocation();

    }
```