# Is there a way of finding cities within a route with Google Maps API?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Is there a way of obtaining the cities a route traced by `DirectionsService.route()` goes through?

For example, in the route in https://goo.gl/maps/trHkPUNzuDFEjYT27 , roads belonging to the cities of Sao Paulo (starting point), Anhanguera, Cajamar, Jundiai, (others...) and Campinas (ending point).

If we input the starting and ending point in the `DirectionsService.route()` method, we obtain a list of `leg`s, which includes the road, mileage, and time to travel, but not the cities they belong to.

Is there a way of obtaining this data *without calling additional API's* ? Cost is an important issue when considering Maps API.

EDIT: Clarified that solution should not involve *additional* calls. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14641899/get-stopover-towns-using-the-google-maps-api-directions) solution is not much better than calling PlacesService for each leg of the route, since it merely boxes parts of the route, and calls them anyways.

Comment: You can reverse-geocode each step (or point you are interested in) and extract the information from the geocoder response.

Comment: That would be awfully cost (and computationally) expensive, since each request to google api is paid.

Comment: Yes I know. And further to that the geocoder is rate limited. But *as you said* the information is not part of the Directions response so... what else do you want to do?

Comment: I'd like to know if there are other parameters that can be used, or other services that can be called.

Comment: Google Maps API's doc is remarkably poor when talking about hidden parameters.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get stopover towns using the Google Maps API (directions)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14641899/get-stopover-towns-using-the-google-maps-api-directions)

Comment: I understand the dupe vote, but why off-topic?

Comment: BTW, the solution in the link provided by @geocodezip is also heavily tolled. `Nearby Search and Text Search return all of the available data fields for the selected place`.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "hidden parameters".  Undocumented parameters should, in general, not be used, as they may change or go away at any time.  Asking for recommendations of other services/APIs is off-topic for StackOverflow.  If the data you are looking for is not in the DirectionsService response, you can't get it without using additional calls to Google Maps (and if there were a way to request additional information in the response, it would cost more).

Comment: By "Hidden parameters", I would mean "parameters that _are_ documented and expected to be used, but won't appear in the current version of the docs". That being said, I did not ask for recommendations of other services, I asked if there were calls that could be used for this purpose.
I understand that DirectionsService would not return these data (otherwise this question would not be relevant), and that additional _call_ must be requested to retrieve them, but I want to avoid _repetitive, multiple_ calls inside Google Maps.

Comment: @EricWu are you running front-end JS or Node? May I ask what server you are running, if it may help in the answer to do the processing via backend code instead of front-end JS?

Comment: @GezaKerecsenyi, I'm running front-end JS. How would you approach the backend proccessing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestions would be simply to abandon the approach of using the Google API for everything. Undoubtedly, it's the best navigation tool, and it's for this reason it's that expensive. So, I'd suggest to use some other method for the geocoding that's not through Google, especially if you're only looking for big cities (as is appears in your example). There's some 'free' APIs that already exist (in truth, they're usually never really free) - I'd only suggest this if you're serverless. In that case, I'd go with Nominatim - it has no limit caps (kind of, see operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/nominatim - you *can* spam it, but it's discouraged), no API keys, and is completely free - the only issue, of course, is that as you mentioned you'd have to go through each point and make a request to an API, which would take a lot of time. However, I'd do:

```
let zoom = 12; // Adjust to your needs: see nominatim.org/release-docs/develop/api/Reverse. Higher numbers will result in more places being matched, while lower numbers will result in faster execution.

let coords = [];

const stepList = [];

Array.from(googleResponse.routes[0].legs).forEach(leg => {
  stepList.push(...leg.steps);
});

stepList.forEach(e => {
  coords.push([e.endLocation.lat, e.endLocation.long]);
});

coords.push([legList[0].startLocation.lat, legList[0].startLocation.long]);

let arr = [];
let promises = [];
let bboxes = [];

const loopOn = (i, cb) => {
  const coord = coords[i];
  const nextLoop = () => {
    i+1 < coords.length? loopOn(i+1, cb) : cb();
  }

  let makeRequest = true;
  for (let bbox of bboxes) {
    if (coord[0] >= bbox[0] 
        && coord[0] <= bbox[1] 
        && coord[1] >= bbox[2] 
        && coord[1] <= bbox[3]){ // If it is within a bounding box we've already seen
          makeRequest = false; // there's no need to geocode it, since we already roughly know it's in an area we have already saved.
          break;
        }
  }

  if (makeRequest){
    var request = $.ajax({
      url: `https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=jsonv2&lat=${coord[0]}&lon=${coord[1]}&zoom=${zoom}`,
      type:'GET',
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      success: resp => {
        thisPlace = resp.address.city || resp.address.town || resp.address.village;
        thisPlace && arr.indexOf(thisPlace) === -1 && arr.push(thisPlace);
        bboxes.push(resp.boundingbox);
        nextLoop();
      }
    });
  } else {
    nextLoop();
  }
};

loopOn(0, () => {
  /*The rest of your code*/
});
```

This code simply goes through each leg (where I'm assuming `googleResponse` is the unfiltered but JSONified response from the Directions API, and requests it from Nominatim. I've made it a tad bit more efficient using Nominatim's bounding boxes, which return the rectangle around each city/village area, so we don't need to make a request if an instruction/step is literally simply to turn a corner in the same square/suburb/city district/city (this can be defined using the `zoom` variable).

The problem with this is that Nominatim, being free and quite unoptimised, is obviously not the fastest API out there. Even if Google's servers ran on a slow connection, they'd *still* be faster simply because they've optimised their product to run faster, using some low-level code. Meanwhile, Nominatim simply does a basic lookup from a file (no rainbow hashing, etc.), so it has to manually narrow down the area.

The solution would be to use a custom dataset. Obviously, this would require a backend to store it on, since downloading the entire CSV to the frontend with each load would take literal hours (and on every reload!). All you'd really need to do for this is replace the AJAX API request with a call to the `csv-parser` module (or any other parsing function), which works in much the same way regarding promises/async, so you could literally just replace the code with the example on their website:

```
let resp = [];

fs.createReadStream(<your file here.csv>)
  .pipe(csv())
  .on('data', (data) => resp.push(data))
  .on('end', () => {
    results = search(resp, coords);
    thisPlace = results.address.city || results.address.town || results.address.village;
    thisPlace && arr.indexOf(thisPlace) === -1 && arr.push(thisPlace);
    nextLoop();
  });
```

Also, you could remove the bounding-box code, since you don't need to save request time anymore.

However, rearranging it like so would be faster:

```
let resp = [];

fs.createReadStream(<your file here.csv>)
  .pipe(csv())
  .on('data', (data) => resp.push(data))
  .on('end', () => {
    let coords = [];

    const stepList = [];

    Array.from(googleResponse.routes[0].legs).forEach(leg => {
      stepList.push(...leg.steps);
    });

    stepList.forEach(e => {
      coords.push([e.endLocation.lat, e.endLocation.lng]);
    });

    coords.push([legList[0].startLocation.lat, legList[0].startLocation.lng]);

    let arr = [];
    let promises = [];
    let bboxes = [];

    coords.forEach(coord => {
      let results = search(coords);

      let thisPlace = results.address.city || results.address.town || results.address.village;
      thisPlace && arr.indexOf(thisPlace) === -1 && arr.push(thisPlace);
    };

    /*The rest of your code*/
});
```

The next thing we need is the actual `search` function, which is the complicated bit. We need to find something that's quick, but also mostly correct. The actual implementation depends on the format of your file, but here's a quick rundown of what I'd do:

- Create two duplicates of `resp`, but sort one (we'll call this array `a_o`) by longitude and the other one by latitude (`a_a`). Ensure you don't use `var` or `let` or `const` when defining these arrays, just... define them.
- For each one, remove anything not within a 25km (radius) of the point on the longitude axis in `a_o`, and the same but with latitude for `a_a`
- `delete` both arrays to clear the space they are taking up in the RAM.
- Find any item that's in both arrays, and put these in an array called `a_c`
- Filter any items which are within 3-4km of each other (make sure to keep one of the points, though, not delete both!)
- Go through each item, and work out the absolute distance to the point (using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27943/6100832) algorithm - remember, the earth is a sphere, basic Pythagorean thereom will **not** work!
- If you find any item with a distance less than 20km, and has a city or village or town attached, break and return the name.
- If you finish, i.e never break, return `undefined`.

Other then that, you can go with mostly any CSV which contains:

- The city's name
- The central latitude
- The central longitude

I hope this helps. In conclusion, go with the first, tried-and-tested, premade method if you're only doing 5-6 simple routes an hour. If you've got gajillions of waypoints, download the data and spend half an hour or so making what is essentially your own geocoding system. It'll well be worth the performance bump.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I'll definitely go for the second option, since the amount of requests is closer to _gajilions_. :)

Comment: @EricWu If it's not too late, see now: I noticed a mistake with the second code example, where I unnecessarily used recursion. This was only done to make a more compactified version when doing requests to the API, but it's not necessary if you're just pushing to an array. Plus, if you are really making *that* many requests, it would cause a `Maximum stack call size exceeded error` - I reasonably would assume, however, that anyone with few enough requests to justify using the API would also not have a problem with some recursion.

Comment: Not late at all :). And yes, recursion is not an issue.